# Why are the official/stable 4.* kernels marked unstable?

Tags: kernel

Kernel.org shows `4.1.1` and `4.1.2` as **stable**.

Why then are they named `*-unstable/*` here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Have you read? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: Source code stable, but kernel will be marked stable once it tested in distro environment with compiled modules for this kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/upgrade-kernel-4-2-ubuntu/):

**NOTE:** The kernel binaries are marked as UNSTABLE (see the link url). You may not do this in a production machine, or you have to know what you’re going to do and know about how to restore if something goes wrong (or see the link at bottom).